# trying to save xml file in unity c# but getting an empty file

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I am tying to save an xml file but the file I get is completely empty, not even the tags.
Even simple files are not being saved correctly, for example:

```
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            XmlElement root = xmlDoc.CreateElement("root");

            XmlElement element = xmlDoc.CreateElement("element");
            root.AppendChild(element); // add element to root

            XmlElement Name = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
            Name.InnerText = "NameElement";
            element.AppendChild(Name); // add Name to element


            xmlDoc.AppendChild(root); // add root to document

            xmlDoc.Save(path);
            if (File.Exists(path))
                Debug.Log("xml saved");
```

I am getting the "xml saved" message in the log but the file that is being created is completely empty.

Comment: From my experience, if you want to save some state of your game use Serialization/Deserialization. Preferably Json (XML is too verbose and basically allows too much), because it's easier to read/maintain (if you change something)/transfer (if you want to store state on server)/use (one-liner). See example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ease. You must to append element to root at the end of method. Firstly insert need data in element. In the end append element to root.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.CreateElement("root");
XmlElement element = xmlDoc.CreateElement("element");
XmlElement Name = new XmlElement("name string")

element.Add(Name); // add Name to element
root.AppendChild(element); // add element to root
xmlDoc.AppendChild(root); // add root to document

xmlDoc.Save(path);
if (File.Exists(path))
Debug.Log("xml saved");
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still creates an empty file.
Even when I tried  to copy and paste the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help!!
It started working with your last solution only after I restarted my computer (no idea why).